# Batch file for loop removes xml comment nodes

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

when I parse an xml file for processing in a batch job, the comment nodes seem to be altered; is this something to do with special characters? how do I prevent it.

A node like this: `<!--Location: D:\\Logs-->`
will look like this when queried through %%G: `< D:\\Logs-->`

A small code sample:

```
        **setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%G in ("%HOMEDRIVE%\Logs\Connections.xml") do (

            set str=%%G     

        echo !str!

            PAUSE

    )

endlocal

    **
```

Comment: you have only 1 problem, the problem of using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: and what do you suggest?

Comment: show the people your input xml file and the output you expect to get, and I will show you better ways to do it than batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got three problems.

1. With delayed expansion, it removes/handles the `!` and carets `^` as special characters, as the `!` is evaluated **after** the expansion of the for-loop-var %%G
2. Some text can't be displayed with a simple `echo`, like `OFF`, `ON` or `/?`
3. Empty lines are removed, as a FOR-Loop don't handle them

To solve 1. you should use the delayed toggling trick
To solve 2. you could use the `echo(` form.

So you get

```
setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%G in ("%HOMEDRIVE%\Logs\Connections.xml") do (
    set "str=%%G"
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!str!
    endlocal
)
```

If you want to solve 3. (empty lines), you could use `findstr /n` to number all lines, so no line is empty, and then remove the number in the loop.

```
setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%G in (`findstr /n "^" "list.txt"`) do (
    set "str=%%G"
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!str:*:=!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is "Location: " removed then?

Comment: @kreid: With enabled delayed expansion, the `!` is evaluated after the expansion of the for-loop-var %%G, so I disable it before

Comment: What exactly is !str:*:=!
 doing?

Comment: @kreid `!str:*:=!`  replaces all until the first `:` with nothing, generally `!str:one=two!` replaces all words `one` with the word `two`, with a prefixed `*` all until the `one` is replaced by a single `two`, see also `set /?`

Comment: Isn't `echo.` the canonical way of outputting something that usually cannot be printed? Interesting, though, that it works with `(` too. And `;`, `=` and a few others. Apparently `cmd` looks just for a space there for `echo on`/`echo off` to work and everything else that doesn't interfere with command parsing is ok to disable the special function.

Comment: @Joey: `echo.` is often referenced, but it's a bad solution, also the `;=`, the complete explanation is here [echo. fails](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774#p4554)

Comment: So apparently every possibility fails on certain input. Hooray!

Comment: Only the `echo(` seems to be stable (currently)

Comment: If I want to use str after endlocal in the for loop, or later on in the batch file, how do I do that?

Comment: It can be done, but as it is an other question, please open/ask a n ew question

Comment: Thanks @jeb. So much knowledge in this answer!